# How to disable gravity in walk mode for Forge Viewer v6

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to disable gravity in Autodesk.BimWalk extension? Currently, the camera will keep descend until a floor is hit. I would like to be able to float in air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with the latest version (6.2+) of Viewer:

```
// disable gravity upon extension load
​viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.BimWalk').then(function(ext) {ext.tool.navigator.enableGravity(false)})

// disable the same post load
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.BimWalk').tool.navigator.enableGravity(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bryan answer.

in your web browser console you could run this command

```
//TURN OFF FIRST PERSON VIEW GRAVITY MODE:
NOP_VIEWER.getExtension("Autodesk.BimWalk").tool.navigator.enableGravity(false)
```